# Magento 2 - Add Dynamic fields in Customer Account Information

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account

I want to add multiple emails into **customers account information** as per below screen-shot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add dynamic custom field in customer edit/create form

[image]

Create file : [Namespace]/[Module]/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="customer">      
            <dynamicRows name="multiple_emails">
                <settings>
                    <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add More</addButtonLabel>
                    <additionalClasses>
                        <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                    </additionalClasses>
                    <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
                </settings>
                <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                            <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">attribute_options.position</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <field name="emja_more_emails" sortOrder="10" formElement="input">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                        <settings>
                            <label translate="true">Email</label>
                            <dataType>text</dataType>
                            <dataScope>emails</dataScope>
                        </settings>
                    </field>
                    <field name="apply_to" formElement="multiselect"  sortOrder="20">
                        <settings>
                            <dataType>text</dataType>
                            <label translate="true">Apply To</label>
                            <disabled>false</disabled>
                            <dataScope>apply_to</dataScope>
                        </settings>
                         <formElements>
                            <multiselect>
                                <settings>
                                    <options class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\EmailTemplates"/>
                                </settings>
                            </multiselect>
                        </formElements>
                    </field>
                    <actionDelete  sortOrder="30">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">500</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
                </container>        
            </dynamicRows>

    </fieldset>        
    </form>
```

Create di file for value selected in dynamic rows

[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="add-size-grouped-products" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Customer\DataProvider" sortOrder="5" />
    </type>
</config>
```

[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Customer;

class DataProvider 
{
    public function afterGetData(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider $subject, $result)
    {

    if($result){
        $customer_id = key($result);
        $customer_data =  $result[$customer_id]['customer'];        

        if($customer_data){
            if(array_key_exists('emja_more_emails',$customer_data)){
                $emja_more_emails = unserialize($customer_data['emja_more_emails']);
                if(count($emja_more_emails) > 0){
                    foreach ($emja_more_emails as  $value) {
                        //$logger->info($value);    
                        $result[$customer_id]['customer']['multiple_emails']['multiple_emails'][] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Create event for save data to customer

[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_before">
        <observer name="multiple_emails_save" instance="[Namespace]\[Module]\Observer\AddMultipleEmails" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

[Namespace]/[Module]/Observer/AddMultipleEmails.php

```
<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Observer;

class AddMultipleEmails implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

     protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;        
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $data = $this->_request->getParams();

        if($data){
            $customerData = $data['customer'];
            $serialize_emails = '';
            if(array_key_exists('multiple_emails',$customerData)){
                $serialize_emails =  serialize($data['customer']['multiple_emails']['multiple_emails']);            

            }
            $customer->setEmjaMoreEmails($serialize_emails);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me